# how the completion function work in readline

Tags: python, autocomplete, readline

I've checked a few examples including

http://pymotw.com/2/readline/

```
class SimpleCompleter(object):

    def __init__(self, options):
        self.options = sorted(options)
        return

    def complete(self, text, state):
        response = None
        if state == 0:
            # This is the first time for this text, so build a match list.
            if text:
                self.matches = [s 
                                for s in self.options
                                if s and s.startswith(text)]
                logging.debug('%s matches: %s', repr(text), self.matches)
            else:
                self.matches = self.options[:]
                logging.debug('(empty input) matches: %s', self.matches)

        # Return the state'th item from the match list,
        # if we have that many.
        try:
            response = self.matches[state]
        except IndexError:
            response = None
        logging.debug('complete(%s, %s) => %s', 
                      repr(text), state, repr(response))
        return response
```

I can't figure out why is state is incrementing and what is its purpose.
It will work fine for state=0 and matched words a list of one element, but when the state increment i'll raise an error (IndexError)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*state* is the number of possible matches, you use it to return multiple result.
i.e. when `state == 1` return "cmd1", when `state == 2` return "command2", when `state ==  3` return None pass a 2 matchs result.